# Why does the decision tree return different solutions for the exact same training data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I was trying out a ML example and it worked for the most part but when I ran the code consecutively python started spitting out different prediction results, now I am now ML expert but that seems wack?

```
# Example file from Google Developers: "Hello World - Machine Learning Recipes": YouTube: https://youtu.be/cKxRvEZd3Mw
# Category: Supervised Learning                                                                               
# January 14, 2018                                                                                            
from sklearn import tree                                                                                      

# Declarations: Texture                                                                                        
bumpy = 0                                                                                                      
smooth = 1                                                                                                     

# Declarations: Labels                                                                                         
apple = 0                                                                                                      
orange = 1                                                                                                                                                                 

# Step(1): Collect training data                                                                               
# Features: [Weight, Texture]                                                                                  
features = [[140, smooth], [130, smooth], [150, bumpy], [170, bumpy]]                                          

# labels will be used as the index for the features                                                            
labels = [apple, apple, orange, orange]                                                                        

# Step(2): Train Classifier: Decision Tree                                                                     
# Use the decision tree object and then fit 'find' paterns in features and labels                              
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()                                                                            
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)                                                                                

# Step(3): Make Predictions                                                                                    
# the prdict method will return the best fit from the decesion tree                                            
result = clf.predict([[150, bumpy], [130, smooth], [125.5, bumpy], [110, smooth]])                             
# result = clf.predict([[150, bumpy]])                                                                         
print("Step(3): Make Predictions: ")                                                                           
for x in result:                                                                                               
    if x == 0:
    print("Apple")                                                                                        
        continue                                                                                              
    elif x == 1:                                                                                              
        print("Orange")                                                                                       
        continue                                                                                              
    print("Orange")
```

[Click link to see vim and bash windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCMRb.jpg)

Answer (score 10):

There's an element of randomness to (most?) Decision Tree algorithms, and your training set is very small which might be exaggerating the effect. The randomness is typically used to determine how many/which samples to use, and in your case there are very few samples.

Try setting the `random_state` to some fixed integer when you create the [`DecisionTreeClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html). If you want a repeatable result for testing, you'll need to use the same "seed" value each time. They use a random seed of zero in the example docs:

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
```

Comment: Most excellent your suggest Taylor worked like a charm, thank you :)

Comment: Despite setting random_state, we are getting different results on each run of decisiontree... What can be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

DecisionTreeClassifier does not build same tree with each run. At each run there are certain hyperparameters considered while building. Here are the 2 cases where randomness is involved in standard DecisionTreeClassifier

**Max_features** : determines the number of features that are considered when evaluating the best split at each node.

a. If max_features is an integer value, let's say n, then at each node,
the algorithm randomly selects n features out of the total available
features and evaluates the best split based on those selected
features.

b. If max_features is a float value between 0 and 1, such as 0.5, then    it represents the fraction of total features to consider at each    split. Here
again picks some features randomly out of available feature at split.

c. If max_features is "sqrt" (or "auto"), then it considers the square    root of the total number of features. For example, if
there are 16    features, it will randomly select the square root of
16 (i.e., 4)    features at each split.

d. If max_features is "log2", it considers the logarithm base 2 of the    total number of features.

**Choosing best split** : If the split criterion is identical for several splits i.e same impurity for more than one features during split, one split has to be selected at random.